# Cucumber | Generic name for the step definition

Tags: cucumber

Is there any generic name for defining a step in Cucumber?

For example, instead using the words Given, When, Then:

```
Given /^I visit the home page$/

When /^I click on (.*?)$/

Then /^I should see (.*?)$/
```

I'd like to use the only common word:

```
Step /^I visit the home page$/

Step /^I click on (.*?)$/

Step /^I should see (.*?)$/
```

Comment: Interesting question - I don't have an answer just yet but I'm curious as to why you'd prefer this?

Answer (score 0):

At Gherkin level you can use `*` like:

```
* I have $50 in my account
```

At step definition layer there is no special word. But Cucumber doesn't look into keyword name when matching steps with step defintions. So you you can do:

```
Then /^I do some test$/
```

will match:

```
Given I do some test
```

But I'm curious why you need this.